# Asp.net ajax autocomplete not working with AutoCompleteExtender

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, autocompleteextender

I want to implement `ajax autocomplete` functionality in my textbox,

I tried like below

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<ajax:AutoCompleteExtender ID="AutoCompleteExtender1" runat="server" TargetControlID="txtCountry"
    ServicePath="~/App_Code/WebService.cs" MinimumPrefixLength="1" EnableCaching="true" CompletionSetCount="1"
    CompletionInterval="1000" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList">
</ajax:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

and in `Webservice.cs`

I tried like below

```
[WebMethod]
public List<string> GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Company_name from Outword_CommonMST where Company_name  " +
                                                        "like '" + prefixText + "%' order by company_name", con);
        //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable  dt = new DataTable( );
        da.Fill(dt);
        List<string> Company_name = new List<string>();
        for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
        {
            Company_name.Add(dt.Rows[i][1].ToString());
        }
        return Company_name;
    }
}
```

but when I am checking it, it is not working.

Also when I checked in the console it was giving something like

> ScriptResource.axd?d=smCBrjG8b3peouydxeU-NDM-jIwTmeeFry083DH5OhjfnWTee0cYnYTLGZX9W7p4AmkPzE7GkZ-MoV…:6076 POST http://localhost:55264/PSITERP%20lite/App_Code/WebService.cs/GetCompletionList 403 (Forbidden)

pls suggest what is wrong here

Comment: the webservice it supposed to end as .asmx and not .cs

Comment: @Dr.Stitch: I added that with `asmx` too but now I am getting error as `ScriptResource.axd?d=smCBrjG8b3peouydxeU-NDM-jIwTmeeFry083DH5OhjfnWTee0cYnYTLGZX9W7p4AmkPzE7GkZ-MoV…:6076 POST http://localhost:55264/PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx/GetCompletionList 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: where is WebService.asmx, same project or different one?

Comment: @Dr.Stitch: It's in the same project.

Comment: try this url in your browser http://localhost:55264/PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx it should show you the list methods available if not it means it doesn't start up.

Comment: @Dr.Stitch: I opened the URL and I am getting like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/NFS8H.png

Comment: @Dr.Stitch: So, what's the next step. I can view all the methods in the URL u gave.

Comment: change your servicepath to PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx

Comment: are you talking about this, i changed it like this `ServicePath="PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx"` is it fine ?

Comment: yes. correct. does it work?

Comment: no, while adding that it gives me error as `PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx nto found` in my aspx page where I am adding the extender

Comment: try this "~/PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx"

Comment: Error in console as `ScriptResource.axd?d=smCBrjG8b3peouydxeU-NDM-jIwTmeeFry083DH5OhjfnWTee0cYnYTLGZX9W7p4AmkPzE7GkZ-MoV…:6076 POST http://localhost:55264/PSITERP%20lite/PSITERP%20lite/WebService.asmx/GetCompletionList 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: sorry, you should be using string array and not List<string>

Comment: try this path as well "~/WebService.asmx"

Comment: where should I change that for string array ?? and how to change. let me know that.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
[WebMethod]
    public string[] GetCompletionList(string prefixText)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbconnection"].ToString());
            con.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select Company_name from Outword_CommonMST where Company_name  " +
                                                            "like '" + prefixText + "%' order by company_name", con);
            //cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", prefixText);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable  dt = new DataTable( );
            da.Fill(dt);
            List<string> Company_name = new List<string>();
            for(int i=0;i<dt.Rows.Count;i++)
            {
                Company_name.Add(dt.Rows[i][0].ToString());
            }
            return Company_name.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry for delay, I get error as **CS0101: The namespace '<global namespace>' already contains a definition for 'WebService'** at line :- `public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {`

Comment: change the class name to any other aside from WebService.

Comment: yup, changed that. Now getting error as **Request format is unrecognized for URL unexpectedly ending in '/GetCompletionList'.**

Comment: In console it says, `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: its done, in place of `dt.Rows[i][1].` i changed it to `dt.Rows[i][0].` and it worked.

Comment: no problem. yes, in C# index is zero based and in your query you only have 1 column so the current index number is 0 and not 1.

Comment: hi, there's one issue related to this. This functionality doesn't works in Visual studio **2.0**